# Get your correct clearance pass!

Tags: mazes, network

I was invited to some super secret meeting at the CIA, and got to the room with the wrong pass.

This shouldn't be too hard - but it's only fun if you feel like a Kafka-esque journey!

If the rules aren't easy to resolve I can add them - but they are a part of the puzzle...

[image]

Comment: the left border is missing - it should be there - and it isn't a clue or anything!